# How to order SOSL results by relevance

Tags: apex, sosl

**How can I order the results of a `SOSL` query by relevance, meaning the result with the most matches of my OR term first?**

I have an Apex class that uses SOSL to find potential duplicates for a new bug ticket.
It splits the new tickets title:

```
Killer function fails with limits
```

into single words, removes stop words and plural 's':

```
Killer function fail limit
```

converts it to a soql query term:

```
Killer* OR function* OR fail* OR limit*
```

and passes it to a SOSL query:

```
FIND :termString 
RETURNING Defect__c(Name, Details__c, Severity__c,   Release__r.Name, Sprint__r.Name, StageOfCompletion__c, FoundInRelease__c 
                    WHERE Project__c = :projId
                    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC) 
                    LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a [Salesforce Community post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/SOSL-default-sort-order/td-p/169927), one user says that results *"should"* be sorted automatically by relevance. To do this in your SOSL query, remove the `ORDER BY` clause.

Try this:

```
FIND :termString 
RETURNING Defect__c(Name, Details__c, Severity__c,   Release__r.Name, Sprint__r.Name, 
    StageOfCompletion__c, FoundInRelease__c 
WHERE Project__c = :projId) 
LIMIT 20
```